# App Xamarin Forms lenta

Tags: xamarin.forms

Tengo una app que cuando genero su apk en release va muy lenta al arrancar. Cuando hago el debugger el arranque es óptimo, bastante rápido. ¿Que puede pasar?. Tengo al arrancar un flash en donde se ve una imagen corporativa.

Gracias,

Comment: ***Microsoft Learn*** tiene una práctica llamada **"Prepare to publish your Xamarin app"** donde aprenderás a preparar tu aplicación en modo release y otras cosas interesantes. [Prepare to publish your Xamarin app](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/prepare-to-publish-your-xamarin-application/)

Answer (score 0):

Emplee la clase StopWatch para medir el tiempo consumido en el tiempo de ejecución. Aquí está el ejemplo: https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stopwatch?view=net-5.0

```
    Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
    stopWatch.Start();
    
    // Tu código va aquí
    
    stopWatch.Stop();
    
    // Obtenga el tiempo transcurrido como un valor de TimeSpan.
    TimeSpan ts = stopWatch.Elapsed;
```

Después de eso, conecte su dispositivo a la computadora y depure su código en el dispositivo, usando la clase StopWatch.

https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stopwatch?view=net-5.0

Le dará una imagen, en qué parte de su código se consume la mayor parte del tiempo.

Comment: Muestra los ejemplos _en la respuesta_. Lee [answer].

Comment: @padaleiana Actualicé mi respuesta